# Azure Mobile Services LoginAsync method not working with Microsoft Auth Token

Tags: oauth-2.0, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services, xamarin.auth, xamarin.uwp

I have successfully been able to get an access_token (or authenticationToken for Microsoft tokens) using the client side authentication in my Xamarin forms App.  I am able to get further user information (email, name, etc.) using the same access token.  Now, when I try to pass that token to my Azure Mobile Service backend, I get a 401 error.

Here is my code:

```
        private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> MSGetUserInfo(Account account)
    {
        // Reference: http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/call_api
        // Note that Microsoft don't recognize the access_token header entry, but rely instead on an Authorization header entry

        var client = new HttpClient();
        var userInfoRequest = new HttpRequestMessage()
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"),
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
        };
        // Add acccess Bearer
        userInfoRequest.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", account.Properties["access_token"]);
        using (var response = await client.SendAsync(userInfoRequest).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Models.User user = new Models.User();
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                var jobject = JObject.Parse(responseString);
                var userName = (string)jobject["userPrincipalName"];
                // Check username is valid
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Username was not set for authenticated user");
                }
                else
                    user.ProviderLoginId = userName;

                var userDisplayName = (string)jobject["displayName"];
                // Replace display name if invalid
                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userDisplayName))
                {
                    userDisplayName = userName;
                }
                else
                    user.Name = userDisplayName;
                var userEmail = (string)jobject["mail"];
                // Replace email if invalid
                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userEmail))
                {
                    userEmail = userName;
                }
                else
                    user.Email = userEmail;

                Valufy.App.currentUser = user;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("OAuth2 request failed: " + await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));
            }
        }
        return "success";
    }
```

The above code snippet works in getting my user details.  Now when I try to use the same token in the subsequent call, I get a 404:

```
        public async Task<bool> Authenticate(string token)
    {
        string message = string.Empty;
        var success = false;
        JObject objToken = new JObject();
        //objToken.Add("access_token", token);  //for facebook and google
        objToken.Add("authenticationToken", token); //for microsoft

        try
        {
            // Sign in with Facebook login using a server-managed flow.
            if (user == null)
            {
                //ProviderAuth("MICROSOFT");
                user = await syncMgr.CurrentClient
                    .LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount, objToken);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    success = true;
                    message = string.Format("You are now signed-in as {0}.", user.UserId);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            message = string.Format("Authentication Failed: {0}", ex.Message);
        }

        // Display the success or failure message.
   //     await new MessageDialog(message, "Sign-in result").ShowAsync();

        return success;
    }
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong?  Any and all assistance is appreciated.

Comment: What does your App Service Authentication configuration look like?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I followed this [Git sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/uwp-csharp-connect-rest-sample) about Microsoft Graph Connect Sample for UWP (REST). I could get the `access_token` and it could work as expected with Microsoft Graph API (e.g. [Get a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get)). But when I use this `access_token` as the `authenticationToken` token object for `MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync`, I could also get **401 Unauthorized**.

Then I checked the managed client for Azure Mobile Apps about [Authenticate users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#a-nameauthenticationaauthenticate-users). For Client-managed authentication flow, I found that the official code sample about using Microsoft Account is working with Live SDK as follows:

```
// Request the authentication token from the Live authentication service.
// The wl.basic scope should always be requested.  Other scopes can be added
LiveLoginResult result = await liveIdClient.LoginAsync(new string[] { "wl.basic" });
if (result.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
{
    session = result.Session;

    // Get information about the logged-in user.
    LiveConnectClient client = new LiveConnectClient(session);
    LiveOperationResult meResult = await client.GetAsync("me");

    // Use the Microsoft account auth token to sign in to App Service.
    MobileServiceUser loginResult = await App.MobileService
        .LoginWithMicrosoftAccountAsync(result.Session.AuthenticationToken);
}
```

Note: As [LiveConnectSession](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.live.liveconnectsession.aspx) states about [AuthenticationToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.live.liveconnectsession.authenticationtoken.aspx):

> The authentication token for a signed-in and connected user.

While check the [authentication with Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/authorization/auth_overview), I could only find the `access_token` instead of `AuthenticationToken`.

**UPDATE:**

I have checked [LiveLogin for WP8](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Windows/blob/master/src/WP8/Samples/LiveLogin/MainPage.xaml.cs) and [Microsoft Account Authentication for Mobile Apps](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/social/#microsoft-account-configuration) via Fiddler to capture the authorize requests. I found that MS account authentication has the similar authorize request as Live SDK.

[image]

I assumed that you need to leverage Live SDK to authenticate the user when using client side authentication with Microsoft account. I found the Live SDK download page is not exist, you could follow the [Live SDK for WP8](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Windows/tree/master/src/WP8) to get started with Live SDK.

**UPDATE2:**

For the client-flow authentication (Microsoft Account), you could leverage `MobileServiceClient.LoginWithMicrosoftAccountAsync("{Live-SDK-session-authentication-token}")`, also you could use `LoginAsync` with the token parameter of the value `{"access_token":"{the_access_token}"}` or `{"authenticationToken":"{Live-SDK-session-authentication-token}"}`. I have tested `LoginAsync` with the `access_token` from MSA and retrieve the logged info as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bruce.  Were you able to resolve the issue? if so, can you share the code.  Especially, I am confused on which libraries to use to use the LiveLoginResult.

Comment: Thanks Bruce.  I noticed that you used response_type=code instead of response_type=token.  Once you get the code, do you then get a token in a separate call?  The reason I am asking is that I need the token to send it back in the LoginAsync call.

Comment: Yes, I just capture the single request...after calling `LiveLoginResult loginResult=await this.authClient.LoginAsync(scopes);`, you could retrieve access_token from loginresult. For more details, you could refer to [here](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Windows/blob/master/src/WP8/Samples/LiveLogin/MainPage.xaml.cs).

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I found some useful info, you could see my update.

Comment: Hi Bruce.  I am still having no luck... Can you post the actual code that you used?  I tried using Microsoft.Graph as well and I am getting essentially the same 401 error.

Comment: Was there ever a resolution on this issue? I'm having the same problem, 401 error...